# Mongoose, can't get data from document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model Users:

```
db.Users.find({username: "some_name"}, function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else if(result) {
      console.log(result);
      console.log(result.username);
    }
});
```

The first console.log returns object:

```
{ __v: 0,
  email: 'some_email@mail.ru',
  password: '123456',
  username: 'some_name',
  _id: 57090f48f0b2dc101a855eb2 }
```

What is strange, i can't get access to those fields...
Second console.log just returns undefined.
So, how do i get this data?

Comment: The result is an array here. Try access it like result[0].username

Comment: Thank you, it works! Btw even typeof result says "Object", that's really strange...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to use findOne() here, since you intend only one User to be returned

```
db.Users.findOne({username: "some_name"}, function(err, result) {
  if(err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else if(result) {
    console.log(result);
    console.log(result.username);
  }
});
```